# Mock class with Configuration as arguments

Tags: scala, typesafe-config, scalamock

How do I mock the class which has Configuration(play.api) injected as arguments to its constructor?

```
class SomeScalaClass @Inject(config: Configuration){
    val someValue = config.get[String]("someValueInConfig")
    def abc:Int = {
     ..
     ..
    }
}
```

I am using scalamock. I am trying to test a class which has "SomeScalaClass" injected as dependency to it:

```
class ClassToTest @Inject()(obj: SomeScalaClass){.....}
```

I am getting error when I do this in my test Fixture:

```
val someScalaClassMock = mock[SomeScalaClass]
val classToTestObj = new ClassToTest(someScalaClassMock)
```

Error is: not found: value someScalaClassMock

I am new to scala so not sure how to tackle this issue. Thanks in Advance

Comment: Please provide the full test code, the error does not match with what you shared.

Answer (score 0):

You can try making *someValue* val as *lazy val* or extracting the config value inside the method definition if required inside a single method.

Or you can use *typesafe config* which does not need any Injection.

```
import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory


val someValue= ConfigFactory.load().getString("someValueInConfig")
```